# Can the Docker FROM version include variables?

Tags: docker, continuous-integration

I suspect the answer to this question is no as the FROM command comes first in the file (before any ENV statements), but can you parameterize the version of the base image that a docker container is created from?

e.g.

```
FROM image-name:4.6.${patchVersion}
```

The reason that I am looking at this is to support CI/CD. I have separated the build container and the deployment container, and the patchVersion of the deployment container is generated by the build. I would also like to generate the patch number of the build container this way, and then reference this from the deployment container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR not only with Docker

Long:

The documentation says:

> Environment variables are supported by the following list of
>   instructions in the Dockerfile:
>
> - ADD
> - COPY
> - ENV
> - EXPOSE
> - LABEL
> - USER
> - WORKDIR
> - VOLUME
> - STOPSIGNAL

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#environment-replacement

You can use `envsubst` https://linux.die.net/man/1/envsubst to rewrite your `Dockerfile` before doing the `docker build`

```
envsubst < Dockerfile.template_with_variable > Dockerfile
docker build .
```